# factoring a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that if a quadratic equation has roots s and t, you can factor it as (x-s)*(x-t) and I used that property countless times, but I have never quite understood why that should be. Any clarification and/or proof of this would be appreciated.

I suspect that st = c/a. Is there any way how to see this?

Comment: if $r_1$ is a root of some function $f(x)$ then this implies that $f(r_1)=0$. Does that help?

Comment: In your case, $f(x)=(x-s)(x-t)$

Comment: Actually, what I don´t undestand is why should the (x-s)(x-t) be equal to the original quadratic equasion.

Comment: @Adam, it is not if $\;a\neq 1\;$ ...it must be $$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-r)(x-s)$$

Comment: @Adam -- its because $f(s)$ and $f(t)$ must both equal zero if $s$ and $t$ are roots of $f(x)$. This means that whatever form your original quadratic equation was in, it MUST be factorable into $f(x)=(x-s)(x-t)$ as this function satisfies both $f(s)=0$ and $f(t)=0$. Assuming the original equation was of the form $f(x)=x^2+bx+c$. If, as DonAntonio pointed out, it is instead of the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, then it would factor to $f(x)=a(x-s)(x-t)$.

Comment: I am probably missing something but what if I constructed from two linear functions a new function (looking somewhat like an absolute value) that would satisfy f(s)=0 and f(t)=0. It obviously wouldnť be equivalent to the quadratic equation.

Comment: @DonAntonio: If $a\neq1$ as in $21x^2-13x-20$ one can achieve $(3x-4)(7x+5)$ as a much nicer factorization.  But harder to get.

Comment: Of course, @MichaelHoppe , yet the OP mentioned the standard, or normalized, factorization $\;(x-r)(x-s)\;$ : two **monic** linear polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\,ax^2+bx+c=0\;$ be our quadratic equation ($\;a\neq 0\;$) and let $\;r,s\;$ be its roots, then

$$r,s=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\;,\;\;\Delta:=b^2-4ac$$

and thus we get (watch it: it's *slightly* different of what you wrote!):

$$a(x-r)(x-s)=a\left(x-\frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\right)\left(x-\frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\right)=$$

$$=a\left(x^2-\frac{\left[-b-\sqrt\Delta-b+\sqrt\Delta\right]}{2a}x+\frac{b^2-\Delta}{4a^2}\right)=a\left(x^2+\frac bax+\frac ca\right)=ax^2+bx+c$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $t$ be a root of the polynomial $f(x)=0$, so that $f(t)=0$.

Now divide $f(t)$ by $x-t$ obtaining $f(x)=g(x)(x-t)+r$ where $r$ is a constant.

If you don't know the method of division, note that $x^n=x^{n-1}(x-t)+tx^{n-1}$, which we can apply until $n=1$, so that we eventually obtain a constant remainder.

Now we note that, with $x=t$ we have $0=f(t)=g(t)(t-t)+a=a$, so that $a=0$ and $x-t$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

Therefore if $t$ is a root of $f(t)=0$ then $x-t$ is a factor of $f(x)$ - and that applies whatever degree $f(x)$ has. Obviously a quadratic polynomial has only two linear factors.

If $f(x)=0$ has roots $s,t$ we can write $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a(x-s)(x-t)=ax^2-a(s+t)x+ast$$

Equating coefficients we get $s+t=-\frac ba$ and $st=\frac ca$